# Problems adding new answers to my Careers profile

Tags: support, jobs

When I paste the link of an answer that I want to be on my answers list, it keeps loading forever:

[image]

**Is it a bug, or is something particular with my internet connection?**
Maybe am I doing the process wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem as [Careers isn't showing all my Stack Exchange accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91272/careers-isnt-showing-all-my-stack-exchange-accounts/91490#91490).  You should be all set.  Let me know if things are still busted.