# Careers isn't showing all my Stack Exchange accounts

Tags: support, jobs

When I try to add other SE accounts to my Careers profile, I only see two of them:

[image]

I'm registered on more than those SE sites with the same OpenID that I'm using in my Careers 2.0 profile.

**Maybe it is because I could have that OpenID as secondary?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a user merge on the network that we didn't pick up.  You should be all set now.

Comment: I have the same problem, I added my 'Super user' account yesterday to my other accounts but I can't select it on my careers profile.